# Múltiplas Aplicações com configurações compartilhadas no Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Tenho múltiplas aplicações no codeigniter onde configurei com base nesse [tutorial](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/managing_apps.html).
Agora minha pasta `applications` está assim:

```
applications/gerencia/
applications/gerencia/config/
applications/gerencia/controllers/
applications/gerencia/libraries/
applications/gerencia/models/
applications/gerencia/views/
applications/loja/
applications/loja/config/
applications/loja/controllers/
applications/loja/libraries/
applications/loja/models/
applications/loja/views/
```

Os dois sistemas estão funcionando normalmente, alterei o `index.php` pegando o `$application_folder`, tudo corretamente, porém surgiu uma dúvida.

Como faço pra dividir alguns recursos entre as aplicações?

Exemplo, se eu for instalar esse projeto em algum servidor, preciso alterar a conexão do banco na pasta `applications/gerencia/config/database.php` e `application/loja/config/database.php`. Porém a conexão é a mesma, como faço pra compartilhar esse recurso e outros entre as aplicações no Codeigniter?

Comment: Se vc usa Linux, pode ser com um link simbólico para o arquivo de configuração do banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver, criei mais uma `application` e o projeto ficou assim:

```
applications/gerencia/
applications/gerencia/config/
applications/gerencia/controllers/
applications/gerencia/libraries/
applications/gerencia/models/
applications/gerencia/views/

applications/loja/
applications/loja/config/
applications/loja/controllers/
applications/loja/libraries/
applications/loja/models/
applications/loja/views/

applications/config/
```

Na pasta `applications/config` tenho o arquivo `database.php` que é responsável pela conexão do meu banco de dados. Então como a `applications/gerencia` e `applications/loja` utiliza a mesma conexão, abri o arquivo `database.php` dessas `applications` e inclui a seguinte linha:

```
include_once(FCPATH . 'applications/config/database.php');
```

E então as duas aplicações reconheceu a conexão.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475629/sharing-config-among-multiple-applications-in-codeigniter